# In the Master Theorem, if one term is smaller than another, can we drop it from the equation and use big O instead of theta?

Tags: runtime-analysis, master-theorem

##### Considering the runtime analysis (with the master theorem) of the function below

$T(n) = 12T(\frac{n}{4}) + 2\sqrt{n} + \log^4(n)$.

---

As I could not figure out a way to get the equation in the form $T(n)=aT(\frac{n}{b}) + \theta(n^d)$, I aimed to get the equation in the form of $T(n)=aT(\frac{n}{b})+\theta(n^k\log^pn)$ as listed [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/advanced-master-theorem-for-divide-and-conquer-recurrences/).

My idea is to drop the $2\sqrt{n}$ term (as $\forall n>\approx 2.5: 
  \log^4(n)>2\sqrt{n}$), and then give the final runtime analysis in big O notation as opposed to $\theta$ notation. **Is this a valid solution?**

---

*Note: this is **similar** to a problem in a homework assignment I am doing, but I have changed things in the equation as I am solely posting to help my understanding and not to cheat.*

Comment: Notice that $\sqrt{n} > \log_{10}(n)^4$ for $n > 400000$ (roughly!) for $log_2$ this happens even earlier. In fact $\log(n)^d \in O(n^\varepsilon)$ for any $\varepsilon > 0,d > 0$, so you should use $\sqrt{n} + \log(n)^4 \in \Theta(\sqrt{n})$

Comment: I have two questions: how is $log(n)^d \in O(n^\epsilon)$ for ANY epsilon and d both greater than zero? What if epsilon is some very small positive number, like 0.0000001, and d is say, 1?

Comment: Also, how can I prove that $\sqrt{n} + log(n)^4 \in \theta(\sqrt{n})$?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you have missed that $\sqrt{n} = n^{1/2}$.

Comment: Wow, I actually did! However, how can I then combine the terms $n^{1/2}$ and $log^4(n)$?

Comment: @Mini, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/824/755

Comment: D.W. This seems very helpful. Thank you! 

I knew the ones about small-omega and small-o, but somehow never saw the rule about theta!